# Is there a way to add a background color in Apple notes?

Tags: notes.app

I'm using MacOs Mojave 10.14.6

I've looked for the function, but can't get any useful info on it. It seems like a simple function to me, but I can't find it on the menu.

Comment: Welcome to the AskDifferent community.
I did a quick check if it was possible to add a background color in Notes.app but, for so far I saw, it's not possible. :-(

Comment: With macOS 12.x you can. Go to Notes -> preferences and look for "Use dark background for note content" checkbox and check. We can have a dark background; no options to choose colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to change the background color in Apple Notes.